# DDD Best solution to delete aggregate

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In DDD i have an aggregate `Lobby`

```
public class Lobby : Entity
{
    public List<User> Users { get; private set; }

    public void RemoveUser(string userId) 
    {
        var user = Users.First(e => e.Id == userId);
        Users.Remove(user);
        if(Users.Count == 0)
        {
            // REMOVE THIS LOBBY
        }   
    }
}
```

And Application Service

```
public class LobbyService : ILobbyService
{
    public void RemoveUser(string lobbyId, string userId)
    {
        var lobby = _lobbyRepository.GetById(lobbyId);
        lobby.RemoveUser(userId);
        _lobbyRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to remove this lobby? Throwing exception / returning specific values or domain event ? However the former solution would mean my Application service would use a bunch of if statements (which I think is bad?) and the latter would mean there would be two database round trips (delete from event handler, and then update from application service since dbContext wouldn't be shared)
Im new to DDD not everything is clear to me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Don't Delete, Just Don't" -- [Udi Dahan, 2009](https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)

That said, if you are going to delete something...

Manipulation of the repository normally happens in the application component; in other words, when the entity is in a particular state, you want to call `delete` instead of save.

```
public void RemoveUser(string lobbyId, string userId)
{
    var lobby = _lobbyRepository.GetById(lobbyId);
    lobby.RemoveUser(userId);

    if(ShouldDelete(lobby)) {
        _lobbyRepository.delete(lobbyId)
    }

    _lobbyRepository.SaveChanges();
}

boolean ShouldDelete(Lobby lobby)
{
    return ????
}
```

> the former solution would mean my Application service would use a bunch of if statements (which I think is bad?)

No, it's not bad - it's just not the common case.

The key idea: application logic and domain logic are different animals.  Application logic belongs in the application, domain logic belongs in the domain model.  "Which I/O operation should we use?" is an application concern, not a domain concern.

---

The more common approach is to schedule the delete to happen later (asynchronously).  There are a lot of different ways to make that happen - the simplest is to have the domain entity document its own end of life, and then at some later time run a "garbage collector" that actually exercises the process to reclaim the unused space.

In that sort of design, your application code would look more like you expect:

```
public void RemoveUser(string lobbyId, string userId)
{
    var lobby = _lobbyRepository.GetById(lobbyId);
    lobby.RemoveUser(userId);
    _lobbyRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the asynchronous garbage collector would be something analogous to

```
DELETE FROM lobby WHERE lobby.should_delete
```

`should_delete` might be a boolean, or it might be a timestamp that is used for comparison against `now()` or some target time, etc.  Many possibilities, different trade offs.

---

You *can* use messaging to communicate with the garbage collector - you get a different set of trade offs.  Messages are another form of I/O, so the application is going to know something about them - but it could be a very generic and re-usable mechanism.

And again, many tradeoffs - are the messages durable or transient? are the part of the database transaction? how much reliability do we have in our message transport solution, and do we need a backup mechanism to ensure that lobbies are deleted even when delete messages are lost?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would still use `if statement` to check if `lobby` is null or not.

```
public class LobbyService : ILobbyService
{
    public void RemoveUser(string lobbyId, string userId)
    {
        var lobby = _lobbyRepository.GetById(lobbyId);

        if (lobby == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Lobby is null"); // or return Result.Error("Lobby is null");
        
        lobby.RemoveUser(userId);
        
        _lobbyRepository.SaveChanges();

        UserRemoved(lobbyId, userId);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's only checking if lobby exists, but what i want is to delete lobby when it became empty, would you do it in event handler of UserRemoved event? But then there would be two database roundtrips (even worse first one would save empty lobby, and in case second one wouldn't be successfull there would be empty lobby in repository which is against the requirements)

Comment: @Fake Yes I would call RemoveLobby from the UserRemoved event handler. No matter how many times the database will be called or the operation is successful or not, that is because the nature of two commands are different. Remove User is a command that need to be done, while remove lobby something like cleaning. Just imagine, if the controller says RemoveUser, would you return error saying I can not remove user because the lobby that the user belongs to was not deleted! that would be wrong I believe.

Comment: @Fake Still, the other option to implement UnitOfWork but this would not be a valid solution for this case, I believe.